# Pandas to match column contents to keywords (with spaces and brackets )

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

A columns in data frame contains the keywords I want to match with.

I want to check if each column contains any of the keywords. If yes, print them.

Tried below:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

Keywords = [

"Caden(S, A)",
"Caden(a",
"Caden(.A))",
"Caden.Q",
"Caden.K",
"Caden"
]

data = {'People' : ["Caden(S, A) Charlotte.A, Caden.K;", "Emily.P Ethan.B; Caden(a", "Grayson.Q, Lily; Caden(.A))", "Mason, Emily.Q Noah.B; Caden.Q - Riley.P"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in Keywords)

df["found"] = df['People'].str.findall(pat).str.join('; ')

print df["found"]
```

It returns Nan. I guess the challenge lies in the spaces and brackets in the keywords.

What's the right way to get the ideal outputs? Thank you.

```
Caden(S, A); Caden.K
Caden(a
Caden(.A))
Caden.Q
```

Comment: `pat = r'(?<!\w)(?:{})(?!\w)'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, sorted(Keywords,key=len,reverse=True))))`? I am not sure it will work as you seem to need all values listed. If there is `W1` and `W1 W2`, you will only have `W1 W2` returned

Comment: Ok, let's remove the comments. Please fix the comma in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you do not need to find *every* keyword, but the longest ones if they are overlapping you may use a regex with `findall` approach.

The point here is that you need to sort the keywords by length in the descending order first (because there are whitespaces in them), then you need to escape these values as they contain special characters, then you must amend the word boundaries to use *unambiguous* word boundaries, `(?<!\w)` and `(?!\w)` (note that `\b` is context dependent).

Use

```
pat = r'(?<!\w)(?:{})(?!\w)'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, sorted(Keywords,key=len,reverse=True))))
```

See an [online Python test](https://ideone.com/sC9cV9):

```
import re
Keywords = ["Caden(S, A)", "Caden(a","Caden(.A))", "Caden.Q", "Caden.K", "Caden"]
rx = r'(?<!\w)(?:{})(?!\w)'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, sorted(Keywords,key=len,reverse=True))))
# => (?<!\w)(?:Caden\(S,\ A\)|Caden\(\.A\)\)|Caden\(a|Caden\.Q|Caden\.K|Caden)(?!\w)
strs = ["Caden(S, A) Charlotte.A, Caden.K;", "Emily.P Ethan.B; Caden(a", "Grayson.Q, Lily; Caden(.A))", "Mason, Emily.Q Noah.B; Caden.Q - Riley.P"]
for s in strs:
    print(re.findall(rx, s))
```

Output

```
['Caden(S, A)', 'Caden.K']
['Caden(a']
['Caden(.A))']
['Caden.Q']
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey don't know if this solution is optimal but it works. I just replaced dot by 8 and '(' by 6 and ')' by 9 don't know why those character are ignored by str.findall ?

A kind of bijection between {8,6,9} and {'.','(',')'}

```
for i in range(len(Keywords)): 
    Keywords[i] = Keywords[i].replace('(','6').replace(')','9').replace('.','8')
for i in range(len(df['People'])): 
    df['People'][i] = df['People'][i].replace('(','6').replace(')','9').replace('.','8')
```

And then you apply your function

```
  pat = '|'.join(r"\b{}\b".format(x) for x in Keywords)
  df["found"] = df['People'].str.findall(pat).str.join('; ')
```

Final step get back the  {'.','(',')'}

```
for i in range(len(df['found'])): 
  df['found'][i] = df['found'][i].replace('6','(').replace('9',')').replace('8','.')
  df['People'][i] = df['People'][i].replace('6','(').replace('9',')').replace('8','.')
```

Voilà